Nodejs/NPM-Setup in Docker Container fails (wrong version / NPM not found)
I'm maintaining an old Laravel project coming form Laravel 6, running in dev-environment in a Docker container with php 7.4, nodejs12, Elasticsearch and MariadDB. The project shall be upgraded to newer versions. Obviously, I'm a beginner to Docker and struggling a bit. Upgrading to Laravel 7 and Laravel 8 incl package-dependencies worked well. Starting the predefined Docker environment shows the deprecation warning because of Node.js 12, but the project ran stable. Somehow, I messed things up while upgrading to php 8.2 and Laravel 9.
What I did:

Upgrade php-version and all package dependencies in my composer.json and run composer update. Composer successes with no conflicts, no vulnerabilities. Working through all relevant upgrade guides of all dependencies and updating my code.

Updating the Docker configuration for php8.2. I intended to only update php-version while running deprecated nodejs12-version in dev and upgrading it later.


My docker-compose.yml:
services:
  php-apache:
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - './docker/${ENV}/php-apache/docker-config:/docker-config'
      - './docker/${ENV}/php-apache/docker-data-init:/docker-data-init'
      - './docker/${ENV}/php-apache/docker-helper:/docker-helper'
      - './docker/${ENV}/php-apache/docker-resources:/docker-resources'
      - './docker/${ENV}/php-apache/entrypoint.d:/entrypoint.d'
      - './docker/${ENV}/php-apache/etc/crontab:/etc/crontab'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    environment:
      - ENV=${ENV}
      - WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/app/public

My docker-compose.dev.yml:
services:
  php-apache:
    image: webdevops/php-apache-dev:8.2
    links:
      - mariadb
      - elasticsearch
  mariadb:
    image: 'mariadb:10.3.13'
    volumes:
      - './docker/${ENV}/mariadb/docker-config:/docker-config'
      - './docker/${ENV}/mariadb/docker-data-init:/docker-data-init'
      - './docker/${ENV}/mariadb/docker-helper:/docker-helper'
      - './docker/${ENV}/mariadb/docker-resources:/docker-resources'
      - './docker/${ENV}/mariadb/entrypoint.d:/entrypoint.d'
      - './docker/${ENV}/mariadb/var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker
  phpmyadmin:
    image: 'phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin'
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    links:
      - 'mariadb:db'
    environment:
      - UPLOAD_LIMIT=1G
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.4.0
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
  adminer:
    image: 'adminer'
    ports:
      - '8090:8080'

Inside projects-directory docker/dev/php-apache/entrypoint.d are the following config files (all files in one code block just to tidy it up a bit in my post):
#file: 100_helper.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "alias ll='ls -la'" >> /root/.bashrc
echo "alias art='php artisan'" >> /root/.bashrc

#file: 200_extensions_system.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y gnupg2


#file: 210_extensions_node.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Install Node.js version 12
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs

echo "Node-Version inside Docker-Container: " && node -v
echo "NPM-Version inside Docker-Container: " && npm -v


#file: 220_extentions_sqlsrv.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
export ACCEPT_EULA=Y
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt-get update -y
apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc unixodbc-dev

pecl install sqlsrv-5.10.1
echo 'extension=sqlsrv.so' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/sqlsrv.ini

pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-5.10.1
echo 'extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini


#file: 300_dependencies_php.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -f /app/composer.json ]; then
    composer install -d /app
fi


#file:310_dependencies_js.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -f /app/package.json ]; then
    npm --prefix /app install
    npm --prefix /app run dev
fi

I run my project with:
export ENV=dev && docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d

Note: I only changed my php-version in docker_compose.yml. I did not touch the docker/dev/-configfiles shown above. The shown configuration worked well with php 7.4, Laravel 6-8. After switching to php8.2, the apache-docker-container crashes.
While executing the 210_extentions_node.sh, it stops at the last line with npm - command not found. Although node.js 12 source was loaded and installed, nom has not been installed with it. When removing the last line (num-command) in 210_extentions_node.sh, docker files while executing the 310_dependencies_ja.sh when trying to run npm --prefix /app install with same error: npm - command not found
Conclusion: npm is not loaded into the container any more.

As workaround, I tried to install npm separately: apt-get install -y nodejs npm

npm installation works, but I get a strange result:

Node-Version inside Docker-Container:
v18.19.0
NPM-Version inside Docker-Container:
9.2.0
(...)
Executing /entrypoint.d/310_dependencies_js.sh
added 60 packages, and audited 1267 packages in 13s
6 packages are looking for funding
run npm fund for details
153 vulnerabilities (3 low, 61 moderate, 54 high, 35 critical)
To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix
To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force
Run npm audit for details.
dev
npm run development
development
cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
10% building modules 7/10 modules 3 active ...?ref--4-0!/app/resources/js/charts.jsnode:internal/crypto/hash:69
this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
^
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at filename (/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/fs-cache.js:76:21)
at /app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/fs-cache.js:107:37
at /app/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:48:26
at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:203:5) {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
Node.js v18.19.0

So my problem comes down to this: Although I want to load node.js 12 and my Docker container throws the typical script deprecation warning" because of ancient nodejs12, after the installation routine, there's node.js v18 and npm v9 running inside, which crashes afterwards with my package-lock.json (created with another npm version).
In ran apt-get remove -y nodejs inside 210_extensions_node.sh before (re-)installing nodejs12. It has no effect.
I also ran npm --version outside docker in my terminal:
npm version
{
npm: '9.6.7',
node: '18.17.0',
acorn: '8.8.2',
ada: '2.5.0',
ares: '1.19.1',
brotli: '1.0.9',
cldr: '43.0',
icu: '73.1',
llhttp: '6.0.11',
modules: '108',
napi: '9',
nghttp2: '1.52.0',
nghttp3: '0.7.0',
ngtcp2: '0.8.1',
openssl: '3.0.9+quic',
simdutf: '3.2.12',
tz: '2023c',
undici: '5.22.1',
unicode: '15.0',
uv: '1.44.2',
uvwasi: '0.0.18',
v8: '10.2.154.26-node.26',
zlib: '1.2.13.1-motley'
}


It's nearly the same version as inside the Docker container. It's just a guess, but maybe, something from outside suddenly seems to affect the nodejs-version inside the Docker container. I did not experience this behavior before.
I already searched Stack Overflow and just got this equivalent: Docker: npm not found But I already tried to implement the suggested solutions (e.g. installing curl, removing nodes before reinstalling, specify version via apt-get install -y nodejs=12.*-1nodesource1 (throws even a "node: command not found" and "npm:command not found"-error)without effect, so maybe my problem differs.
So:

Why does Docker load node.js 18 instead of node.js 12?
Any ideas how to force Docker to use nodejs12?
Any ideas why npm-command is not available inside Docker any more without explicitly installing it, although it should come with nodes-installation out of the box?
Any ideas how to fix this?


The repository your docker container is pulling from likely has a more modern (yet outdated) LTS for NodeJS in its packages.
You could try installing NPM via NVM (Node Version Manager), it will give you more control over the version you want to install.
ENV NODE_VERSION=12.13.0
RUN apt install -y curl
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}


Thank you! Have read somewhere, nvm shall not be used inside a docker container, so I didn't try it out first. But it seems to work fine.
